# Laravel with с перебором

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно выбрать все  модели `model1` где `not_needle_id` в `model2` не совпадает с передаваемым параметром. `model2` - связан с `model1` и отображается при дебаге...

```
$plans = $section->model1()->with(['model2'  => function ($q) use ($notNeedle) {
              $q->where('not_needle_id', '<>', $notNeedle->id);
        }])->active()->get();
```

Но почему то `$q->where('not_needle_id', '<>', $notNeedle->id);` - просто игнорируется....
Вот строка SQL запроса

```
"select * from `model1_table` where `model1_table`.`section_id` = ? and `model1_table`.`section_id` is not null and `status` = ? and `model1_table`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

Как мне быть?

Comment: А вы уверены что отношение coachToTariffPlans принадлежит и находится в TariffPlan?

Comment: Да 100% Дебажил и там было

Comment: Не видел ни одного примера такого использования ни в офиц. документации, ни на других сайтах. Обычно используется ModelClass::with, либо $Model->with.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov ну просто выбрать модели а потом делать еще цикл для перебора - тоже не норм

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `return  $q->where('not_needle_id', '<>', $notNeedle->id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вот так:

```
$plans = $section->model1()->with(['model2'])->whereHas('model2', function ($q) use ($notNeedle) {
          $q->where('not_needle_id', '<>', $notNeedle->id);
    }])->active()->get();
```

whereHas определяет количество связей, и на присутствие отношения. Можно и просто через where.

Comment: Но в таком случае, будет выдан результат только у тех, у которых есть model2. Но ведь есть такие, у которых и нет этой связи. Их тоже нужно

Comment: Вот рабочий вариант:

$plans = $section->model1()->doesntHave('model2')->orWhereHas('model2', function ($q) use ($notNeedle) {
          $q->where('not_needle_id', '<>', $notNeedle->id);
    }])->active()->get();

Comment: Я поэтому и написал про where, который может использоваться вместо whereHas так как не знаю все требования.